# How to use case statement inside where clause in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, case

I'm getting  PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword error when i run the following script

```
create or replace procedure testing
(ass_line in char,
 curs out sys_refcursor
)
is
begin
open curs for 
select asl.Production_Group,asl.last_sequence_nbr
from ASSEMBLY_LINE asl
where(case 
   when ass_line='551F'
     then asl.assembly_line in('551F','551C','551S')
   else
     asl.assembly_line=ass_line
   end);
end;
```

Please help me out

Comment: Apart from semantically incorrect `case` expression, it's not allowed to select `into` a cursor variable use `open <cursor_variable> for` statement

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov. Thank u for the reply.I have updated my post. I run the procedure as mentioned in the post, But I'm getting missing keyword when compiling the procedure.

Comment: See Tony's and/or David's answer.

Comment: fyi you should really be using `varchar2` for strings (or `table.column%type`), not `char`, which has a range of quirks that are more likely to cause odd bugs than be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those who land here that actually have a need for a case statement in a where clause.

```
 where (case
          when ass_line = '551F' then
           case
              when asl.assembly_line in ('551F', '551C', '551S') then
               1
              else
               0
           end
          else
          case
             when asl.assembly_line = ass_line then
              1
             else
             0
          end
       end) = 1
```

Comment: you are missing CASE / END  keywords after the second else

Comment: @Rene. Thanks a lot for the reply.It works. Can u please tell me about "end) = 1" at the end ? Wat does happen when 1 is assigned at the atlast? Wat does dat 1 represent?

Comment: It is not an assignment but a relational operator. The result of the case statement is either 1 or 0. You select only the records where the case statement results in a 1.
Thanks for accepting this as the answer but Tony Andrews solution is a lot more straightforward and, in my view, the better answer.

Comment: I only gave this answer to show how to use a case statement in a where clause. Some people may be looking for this and the title of your question may have lured them to this page.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `case` like that, you must use `or`:

```
select asl.Production_Group,asl.last_sequence_nbr 
from ASSEMBLY_LINE asl
where(  (ass_line='551F' and asl.assembly_line in('551F','551C','551S')
     or (asl.assembly_line=ass_line)
     );
```

Comment: Thank u for the reply. But it is showing the same error.

Comment: That's because you cannot select into a cursor variable (see Nicholas's comment on your question)

Comment: .So can I use nested table ?

Comment: Yes, or you can write `open curs for <your select statement>`.

Comment: I have updated my post. I run the procedure as mentioned in the post, But I'm getting missing keyword when compiling the procedure.

Comment: @BabyboBNukes Yes, your SQL is still incorrect as my answer said!

Answer (score 4):

You ought to be using:

```
where (ass_line  = '551F' and asl.assembly_line in('551F','551C','551S')) or
      (ass_line != '551F' and asl.assembly_line = ass_line)
```